# A-Frame 360 video in iPhone

Tags: aframe

I am able to run a 360 video in iphone but when I hit the VR button I just get two blank 'eyes'.

Any help would b appreciated.

Cheers

Allen

Comment: Could you give some code you try?

Comment: Without code is hard to help. FWIW, A-Frame examples (https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/) work fine for me on iPhone X (iOS 14.4)